# Как прилепить progress bar для отправки запроса retorofit2?

Tags: android, retrofit

Хочу сделать показ прогрес бара при отправке запроса в приложении. Но не простого а с процентами. Сейчас у меня при отправке запроса выводится простенький бар из либы:

```
 private void showDialog() {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mcontext);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog);
        Objects.requireNonNull(dialog.getWindow()).setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

        CircleProgressBar circleProgressBar = dialog.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        circleProgressBar.setColorSchemeColors(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.YELLOW, Color.MAGENTA);

        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();


    }
```

но это не очень интересно наблюдать как крутится бар например секунд 10. Я хочу приделать к бару проценты чтобы показывало сколько процентов выгружено на сервер и сколько осталось. Возможно ли это сделать??? Лично я вижу такое приблизительное решение:

1. Получаем размер отправляемого json (пока не нашел как получать).
2. Получаем скорость сети - [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53393180/determine-transfer-rate-of-upload).
3. Считаем за сколько мы сможем выгрузить этот json.
4. Показываем это все в баре.

Comment: Скорость сети, тем более мобильной, не предсказуема - поэтому подобные вещи надо делать на подсчёте полученных/отправленных байтов, а не на расчётном времени, которое почти наверняка не совпадёт с реальным. Для этого нужен контроль процесса выгрузки. На en-SO есть такой пример: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33384551.

Comment: @woesss, я так понимаю что в моем случае нужно будет контролировать выгрузку json-a?

Comment: А стоит ли вообще - он реально выгружается 10 секунд? В сетях 3G и выше на сто-килобайтном json'е прогресс просто мелькнёт и никто не заметит, что там было написано.

Comment: ну вот например если json не 100 кб а 3-5к то что тогда?)

Comment: 3-5 кБ? Тогда тем более не стоит овчинка выделки.

Comment: ладно я перефразирую - 3000-5000 максимум 20 000))

Comment: 1 килобайт = 1024 байт = 1024 символов латиницы (кириллицы может быть меньше в 2 и более раз, в зависимости от кодировки). В 3G сети 1 мегабайт (грубо говоря 1 000 000 байт) загружается 1-2 секунды, выгружается, возможно несколько дольше. В общем дальше считайте и решайте - надо ли оно Вам.

Answer (score 1):

[Вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338181/is-it-possible-to-show-progress-bar-when-upload-image-via-retrofit-2) есть то, что вам нужно. Но я бы на вашем месте все таки задумался стоит ли оно того. Сделать отображение прогресса адекватным все равно будет не так просто, даже с этим примером, а если прогрессбар будет 90% времени торать на 10%, а потом мгновенно заполнится на 100, смысла от него не много

Comment: Из моего комента ссылку скопировали? )))

Comment: честно, сам прогуглил))